# How to check if current time is greater than jwt exp(expiration time) in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, timer, token, jwt

I'm a beginner in swift. I've got json web token (jwt) and after extraction I have this payload:

**exdate**": 2016-07-13 10:55:27, 
 "**pack_id**": 1, 
"**sub**": 10510, "pack_tag": R,

"**ref**": sxojAVrPADqrVrJ2JiS8j0JMmQIVSKNepaagwBte9vJH1pSDE2OBhUcia59u2q0tOXTcDSBtsZ1I40yMnkmdAg==,

"**nbf**": 1465891091, "**exp**": 1465892291,  "**iat**": 1465891091 etc.

Now, My target is when the current time is greater than the **exp** I will refresh the token **ref** from the server. Now the question is: How can i check current time is greater than the **exp**?

Comment: I can get current date and time by NSDate, but I need timespan of above **exp** formate so that i can compare.

Answer (score 1):

Here it is updated for Swift 5 ([JWT Formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39926104/what-format-is-the-exp-expiration-time-claim-in-a-jwt)).

```
//Time in seconds since 1970.
let expiry = 1465891091

//if expirationDate > Now
if Date(timeIntervalSince1970: Double(expiry)) > Date() {
    print("JWT hasn't expired yet.")
} else {
    print("JWT has expired.")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()

    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss"

    let dateTimeStamp = NSDate(timeIntervalSince1970:1465891091)
    let now = NSDate()
    if( now.timeIntervalSinceDate(dateTimeStamp!) > 0 ) {
        print("now > dateTimeStamp")
    } else {
        print("Nope")
    }
```

Comment: actually I dont need an expdate, I have expiration time (exp) in json web token  which is **1465891091** in Numeric Date formate . How can i check if the jwt expiration time is over?

Comment: `let dateTimeStamp = NSDate(timeIntervalSince1970:1465891091)` and then compare like in answer.

Comment: Thank you. Working fine!