# What format is the exp (Expiration Time) claim in a JWT

Tags: jwt, azure-active-directory, adal

I am using ADAL library to get access token for a resource. Does anyone know what format is the expiration time in ? more specifically
`"exp" (Expiration time) claim`.

`JwtSecurityToken` class simply returns int32 after parsing. So, that is not a good indicator.

Tried parsing it to `TimeSpan` and `DateTime` but the values are not 90 minutes apart. It's almost the same.

This is what I get from fiddler for `iat` and `exp` claim (used https://jwt.io/ to parse the token)

`iat`: 1475874457

`exp`: 1475878357

The values are not that much apart.

Comment: `1475878357 - 1475874457 = 3900 sec`, `3900 sec / 60 sec = 65 min` (1 hour token lifetime + 5 minutes for clock skew)

Comment: What platform are you using?

Comment: Using .NET on windows

Comment: new Date(expires_at * 1000)

Comment: I was going to make a disparaging comment about .NET's choice to use an `int32` value for a UNIX timestamp (2038 gets close every second!) but it looks like the question inaccurately reports on the `JwtSecurityToken` class. It returns a `DateTime` and not an `int32`. Where did you get the `int32` thing?

Answer (score 237, accepted):

RFC 7519 states that the [`exp`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7519#section-4.1.4), [`nbf`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7519#section-4.1.5), and [`iat`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7519#section-4.1.6) claim values must be `NumericDate` values.

`NumericDate` is the last definition in [Section 2. Terminology](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7519#section-2), and is defined as the number of **seconds** (*not milliseconds*) since Epoch:

> A JSON numeric value representing the number of seconds from
> 1970-01-01T00:00:00Z UTC until the specified UTC date/time,
> ignoring leap seconds.  This is equivalent to the IEEE Std 1003.1,
> 2013 Edition [POSIX.1] definition "Seconds Since the Epoch", in
> which each day is accounted for by exactly 86400 seconds, other
> than that non-integer values can be represented.  See RFC 3339
> [RFC3339] for details regarding date/times in general and UTC in
> particular.

Comment: I was looking for which format JWT token exp derives from (I know it's EPOCH but in seconds or milliseconds), and this answers my question.

Comment: Can be converted to Javascript DateTime like this: `new Date(exp_in_seconds * 1000)` (where Javascript requires miliseconds since epoch; a [Unix timestamp](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date#Unix_timestamp))

Comment: @TheRedPea I think your comment can be potentially misleading because of the part "; a Unix timestamp". A Unix timestamp specifies the number of **seconds**. A JSON Web Token uses the number of **seconds**. JavaScript Date uses the number of **milliseconds**.

Comment: Thanks @Vincent you're right, that's why I multiply by 1000. Still my post implies they are the same unit; they're different units as you point out (JWT timestamp in **seconds**, but Javascript Date requiring **milliseconds**);  but both JWT and Javascript Date constructor use the idea **"since the epoch"**.

Comment: A simple solution to this problem is given in this blog post, which creates a extension method for handling that.
https://kmatyaszek.github.io/2018/09/07/jwt-exp-convert-datetime-to-unix-timestamp.html

Answer (score 11):

Les provided the right answer. If you want to quickly convert a NumericDate to a date, you can do it using the following PowerShell command:

```
$numericDate = '1636027948'
([DateTime]('1970,1,1')).AddSeconds($numericDate)
```

Output:

```
Thursday, 4 November 2021 12:12:28
```

Answer (score 0):

The expiration time in a JWT is represented in epoch timestamp format, also known as Unix time, which is a widely used date and time representation in computing. It measures time by counting the number of non-leap seconds that have passed since 00:00:00 UTC on January 1, 1970, known as the Unix epoch.

With .NET Core 2.1 or later, you can convert epoch timestamps to datetime as follows:

```
var expires_on = "1711578241"; 
var expirationDateTime = DateTime.UnixEpoch.AddSeconds(expires_on);
```

This will return "3/27/2024 10:24:01 PM".