# How to generate JWT exp claim with java-time?

Tags: clojure, jwt, java-time, date-parsing

Most examples for JWT token use [clj-time](https://github.com/clj-time/clj-time) which is now deprecated in favor of native java.time. I'm trying to use [java-time](https://github.com/dm3/clojure.java-time) along with [buddy](https://github.com/funcool/buddy) to sign/verify tokens but I'm stuck trying to pass the exp claim to my token. Here's an example of what I have:

```
(ns test-app.test-ns
  (:require
   [buddy.sign.jwt :as jwt]
   [buddy.auth.backends.token :as bat]
   [java-time :as t]))

(def secret "myfishysecret")

(def auth-backend (bat/jws-backend {:secret secret
                                    :options {:alg :hs512}}))
(def token (jwt/sign {:user "slacker"
                      :exp (t/plus (t/local-date-time) (t/seconds 60))
                      } secret {:alg :hs512}))
```

When tyring to test if I can unsign the token

```
(jwt/unsign token secret {:alg :hs512})
```

I get the following error:

> Execution error (JsonGenerationException) at
> cheshire.generate/generate (generate.clj:152). Cannot JSON encode
> object of class: class java.time.LocalDateTime:
> 2021-01-22T12:37:52.206456

So, I tried to pass the same by encapsulating the call to (t/plus ...) inside a (str) but then I get this error:

> class java.lang.String cannot be cast to class java.lang.Number
> (java.lang.String and java.lang.Number are in module java.base of
> loader    'bootstrap')

So, I'm stuck since I don't really know how to generate a valid exp number value using java-time (according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39926104/what-format-is-the-exp-expiration-time-claim-in-a-jwt) question, format should be in seconds since the epoch). [Older examples using clj-time](https://github.com/funcool/buddy-auth/blob/master/examples/jws/src/authexample/web.clj#L62) just passed the exp claim value as

```
(clj-time.core/plus (clj-time.core/now) (clj-time.core/seconds 3600))
```

Any help is highly appreciated.

EDIT: Alan Thompson's answer works perfectly, for what's worth this would be the equivalent using the java-time wrapper:

```
(t/plus (t/instant) (t/seconds 60))
```

Comment: Where is the conversion to JSON happening? You could add a custom encoder for `java.time.LocalDateTime`.

Comment: @Lee I suspect is coming from calling (jwt/unsign ...)
Edit: It is [link]https://github.com/funcool/buddy-sign/blob/master/src/buddy/sign/jwt.clj#L131

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are 2 ways to do it:

```
  (let [now+60          (-> (Instant/now)
                          (.plusSeconds 60))
        now+60-unixsecs (.getEpochSecond now+60)]

    (jwt/sign {:user "slacker" :exp now+60         } secret {:alg :hs512})
    (jwt/sign {:user "slacker" :exp now+60-unixsecs} secret {:alg :hs512}))
```

and we have the `now` results:

```
now+60            => <#java.time.Instant #object[java.time.Instant 0x7ce0054c "2021-01-22T19:04:51.905586442Z"]>
now+60-unixsecs   => <#java.lang.Long 1611342291>
```

So you have your choice of methods.  It appears that buddy knows how to convert from a `java.time.Instant`, so going all the way to unix-seconds is unnecessary.

You may also be interested in this [library of helper and convenience functions](https://cljdoc.org/d/tupelo/tupelo/21.01.06/api/tupelo.java-time) for working with `java.time`.