# How to find JWT Token expiry time in seconds?

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot

I have working jwt token in springboot app in backend then I'm used that token react front end app. now I want to backend token expiry time set and stored console...

```
const decodedToken = jwt_decode(token); 
localStorage.setItem("time", decodedToken.exp); 

console.log(localStorage.getItem("time"))
```

Using the above code to retrieve the expiry time in seconds. But it return this code 1661342806.

Comment: What do you mean you want the expiry time in seconds? How many seconds until your token expires? Your token expired August 24, 2022 12:06:46 PM.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What format is the exp (Expiration Time) claim in a JWT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39926104/what-format-is-the-exp-expiration-time-claim-in-a-jwt)

Comment: I need get time only. Not date and month.

Answer (score 0):

The number you are returning is the number of seconds since `January 1, 1970 12:00:00 AM GMT`. To get the time portion (as you indicated in your comments), you'd first need to convert it to a date, and then just take the time portion of that date.

For example:

```
var unixTimestamp = localStorage.getItem("time"); // 1661342806 
var d = new Date(unixTimestamp * 1000).toLocaleTimeString();
```